# Problema con lectura de una API con Axios y React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

estoy aprendiendo a consumir APIS con Axios y React, y tengo un pequeño problema, al momento de acceder al array de la api me sale de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual esta bien por que es la forma que tengo de poder mostrar a todos los pokemons con un recorrido .map por que lo convierto a un objeto (Si no mal entendí, si estoy diciendo algo estúpido por favor corríjanme)

```
 console.log(' Intentando acceder a las imagenes=  ', {pokemons}.pokemons[3].url)
```

Lo que me devuelve la consola es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, entro a la URL y lo que me muestra es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la forma en la que lo razone yo es poner el .sprite al final del console.log, pero me devuelve un undefined.

No se como hacer para manipular las cosas dentro de la url que me devuelve la API.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

El codigo donde obtengo la API es el siguiente:

```
  componentDidMount() {

axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151&offset=151') //Solicitud api
  .then(({ data }) => {
    console.log(data.results.url);
    const { results: pokemons } = data;
    this.setState({ pokemons });

    console.log(' Intentando acceder a las imagenes=  ', {pokemons}.pokemons[3].url.sprites)
  })



}
```

Comment: Pero no entiendo a que dato quieres acceder.. ¿?

Comment: A cualquiera dentro de pokemons.url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hacer una nueva petición al API con la url para obtener los datos
:

```
 axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151&offset=151') //Solicitud api
          .then(({ data }) => {         
            const { results: pokemons } = data;          
            axios.get(pokemons[3].url)
              .then(({data}) => {
                console.log(data.sprites)                
              })    
            
            this.setState({ pokemons });
          })
```

Comment: Deberia hacer la peticion dentro del mismo componentDidMount ?

Comment: No me funciona, no me paran de salir errores

Comment: Si dentro de componentDidMount, aunque también podría estar separado en su propio método. Te dejo el codesandbox del ejemplo: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-hamilton-nxc55?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Gracias, voy a probarlo mañana por la mañana

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio, aprendi otra cosa que se puede hacer con axios, pero tengo otra duda, como puedo hacer para agarrar la url de todos los pokemon, porque de esa forma solo obtengo la imagen de uno